# How to modify a perl variable and reload the page again?

Tags: javascript, html, perl

Actually I have html textboxes and a button and if i click on the button the variables in the textbox should be saved in a predefined perl variable and the page should reload with the values of the variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some grave misconceptions about your needs. There is no Perl variable for the JavaScript to assign to since the script that generated the HTML is no longer running.

If a CGI application requires persistent state across requests, a sessions is required. A session ties requests together by storing the state somewhere (anywhere) between requests. In order to achieve this, a token ("session id") must be provided to the client, and echoed back in future requests to the server. Cookies are usually used for this.

Hopefully, that will give you a pointer as to where to start your education.

Comment: ok thank you.. but can i call a perl subroutine from a button action of html?

Comment: There are no Perl subroutines for the JavaScript to call. The script that generated the HTML is no longer running. If you want to run code on the server, you will need to place another HTTP request to the server. Read up on AJAX.